# What is the proper way to encode the value of an onClick attribute on an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html-encode, html

I have an HTML element on an ASP .NET page which looks something like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="<%=GetOnClick(param1) %>" />
```

The GetOnClick function looks like this:

```
Function GetOnClick(param1 As String) As String

  Dim onClick As String

  onClick = "foo(" & JavaScriptEncode(param1) & ");"

  Return HtmlAttributeEncode(onClick)

End Function
```

I am thinking I need to JavaScriptEncode (as a string - this method adds the single quotes) the param1 variable, then HtmlAttributeEncode the entire thing, since I'm setting it on the onClick attribute. I am sure I could get away with not having all this encoding for 90% of cases, but is this best practice?

**Edit:**

Bryan brought up a good point. If you can control the string param1 contains, you don't need to encode it. However, in this case it is user input, so I need to be very careful with it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on a couple of things we don't know about... where is param1 coming from?  And what is foo() expecting?

You really don't even need the JavaScriptEncode if you are controlling what param1 contains on the back end.  If it's originating from some user input, then of course you need to clean it or encode it.  But you shouldn't need to encode it twice either.

Comment: it is user input. i've edited the question to reflect this change.